# $\frac{z}{e^z - 1}$ power series at $z = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a the following question:

> Show that $f(z) = \frac{z}{e^z - 1}$ at has a removable singularity at $z = 0$ and that $f$ has power series expansion $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nz^n$. Calculate $c_0$ and $c_1$ and show that $c_{2n+1} = 0$ for $n \geq 1$. Find the radius of convergence.

It is pretty clear that this function has a removable singularity at $0$ and can be analytically continued to all of $\mathbb{C}$ by defining $f(0) = 1$. Thus, $f(0) = 0$. I also calculated $f'(0)$ by dividing power series and got $-1/2$.

Now, we have

$$f(z) - 1 - \frac{1}{2}z = \sum_{n=2}^\infty c_nz^n $$

My plan was to look at how $f(x) - 1 - (1/2) x$ behaves for real $x \neq 0$. Specifically, I was thinking of showing that $f(x) = f(-x)$ which would imply that all of the odd coefficients in the power series would be $0$. I am wondering if this is a valid strategy? If so, this is not true. I have calculated a few values of $f(x) - 1 - (1/2)x$ and it is not true that this function is odd. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

Let $g(z)$ be given by

$$g(z)=\frac{z}{e^z-1}-\left(1-\frac z2\right)$$

Then note that

$$\begin{align}
g(-z)&=\frac{-z}{e^{-z}-1}-1-\frac z2\\\\
&=\frac{z(e^z-1)+z}{e^z-1}-1-\frac z2
\end{align}$$

Can you wrap this up?

Comment: Ah, I must have made a computation mistake. This shows that all the odd coefficients are $0$. Does the power series converge on all of $\mathbb{C}$ (considering $f$ is analytic at each point in $\mathbb{C}$)?

Comment: The series doesn't converge for all $z$.  Note that $e^z-1=0$ for $z=i2n\pi$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.  So there are poles along the imaginary axis at integral multiples of $2\pi$. Hence, the series has a radius of convergence equal to $2\pi$.  That is, the series converges for $|z|<2\pi$.

Comment: Thank you for your response

Comment: You're welcome Mike.  My pleasure.